# how to retrieve php function value and formatted data in html table

Tags: php, html, class

This is my function, through this function i can fetch result of many queries by request parameters.Problem is on using return function remain silent doesn't display anything but on using echo or print it shows.

```
public function select_query( $query ) {

        if ( $result = $this->_mysqli->query( $query ) ) {

            /* fetch object array */
            while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() ) {

                //printf( "%s", $row[0] );
                //print $row[0];
                return $row[0];
            }

            $result->close();
        }
    }
```

When i initialize my class and using this function, i didn't capture the value in table format, like this:

```
echo '<table border=1><tr>';

        echo '<td>'. date('Y-m-d', time() - 13*24*60*60) .'</td>';
        echo '<td>' .$init->get_req_data($_POST['ex'], date('Y-m-d', 24*60*60)). '</td>';

        echo '</tr></table>';
```

In this, i didn't get value of $init in table, it shows value outside of table instead date shows in table structure. Another query is i have to call php self function for retrieving data in same page as i did, but code print php value above of my html, if i am trying to store values in html table then it shows an class error when page is open. Please help me on this issue. Any help would be grateful to me,

Answer (score 1):

first thin I see is function to retrieve data is `select_query` and you call `get_req_data`

in your table.

Comment: yeah i passed a query from **get_req_data** and then execute it through **select_query** function

Answer (score 0):

You're using return in a loop. This is bad. This will return only the first value.

Use a variable to store all values, and return that variable towards the end of your function.